# Angular 2 variable outside component

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a page that calls in a component:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar class="contact_navbar">
    <ion-title>About us</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content>
     <ck-about [channel]="ionic" [template]="template_1"></ck-about>
</ion-content>
```

Now, instead of the `About us` text, how can i add a variable that can be defined in the ck-about component and passed on in here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that using `@ViewChild` and then using the `ngAfterViewInit` you could set the Text for About Us.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'someDir',
  templateUrl: 'someTemplate',
  directives: [ItemDirective]
})
class SomeDir {
  @ViewChild(ItemDirective) viewChild:ItemDirective;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // viewChild is set
  }
}
```

This is just 1 way of the others to do it, but most importantly its the preferred way of doing it.

Comment: `@Directive({
  selector: 'child-dir',
  exportAs: 'child'
})
class ChildDir {}

@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  template: `<child-dir #c="child"></child-dir>`,
  directives: [ChildDir]
})
class MainComponent {
}`

I have used something like this to export my variable into the page view .. it seems that this is kindof what I needed. I kindof needed the variable visible in the page and not in the controller.
Do you think this is ok ?